# Groovy compiler does not accept java 8 Lambdas

Tags: groovy, closures, java-8

As , we know , Groovy syntax accepts closures . 
Today also, Java 8 adds in its syntax closure .

However , When i write java8 closure in groovy file , i get an error like the following :

```
Person.findAll().stream().filter(e-> e.age > 20)
```

We get this error :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 7: unexpected token: -> @ line 7, column 39.
   Person.findAll().stream().filter(e-> e.controllerId > 0)
                                         ^

1 error
```

Nevertheless  , the following works successully :

```
Person.findAll().stream()
```

Comment: Groovy is scheduled to accept Java's 8 syntax on [version 3](http://www.infoworld.com/t/java-programming/one-now-two-later-groovy-updates-add-java-8-support-242229)

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a question.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Yeah, the Groovy parser does not accept Java 8 Lambdas (not closures).

You can use a closure in place of it (assuming you're on Groovy 2.3.*)

ie:

```
Person.findAll().stream().filter( { e -> e.age > 20 } )
```

### edit:

Groovy 3.0+ will accept lambda format

Comment: Groovy is scheduled to accept Java's 8 syntax on version 3

Comment: Really , java 8 will let all programmer to not return to groovy

Comment: @AbdennourToumi Apart for the ease of scripting, meta-programming, dynamic types, AST transformations, data parsing, ease of DSL creation, and being able to Grab resources, you may be right ;-)

Comment: I tried following code in Groovy and "x" is the array and not an element. "Arrays.stream(array).filter({
            x -> x.equals(dependent) || x.equals(governor)
        }).toArray();" Any suggestions?

Comment: @DaSh my guess is that what you have named `array` is a list

Comment: @tim_yates using @CompileStatic in this case generates compilation errors "filter in java.util.Stream cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure". IntelliJ's proposed fix was something on the order of `lst.stream().filter({ from, to -> to.equals(node) } as Predicate<? super Tuple>)`. This is as of Groovy 2.4.5. Thoughts? (For reference, the lst var was a Set<Tuple>)

Comment: @tim_yates Please, add a variant for two arguments lambdas, for in Java it needs braces, and in Groovy we need to omit them. And thank you, it helped anyway.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI it's 2021 w/ Java 16 fairly well established in the wild and I still *very* much prefer Groovy over Java ¯\_(ツ)_/¯