# Write Java8 Lambdas in Groovy 1.x

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, java-8, spock

Is there a way to write Java8 lambda expressions in groovy 1.x? 
I know that groovy 2.3.x supports Java8 lambda expressions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906748/groovy-compiler-does-not-accept-java-8-lambdas) but is it possible to write a Java 8 lambda in groovy? 
I have some Java 8 code that I'm testing with Spock, but my project is stuck using groovy 1.x.

Comment: I do not understand this: "I know that groovy 2.3.x supports Java8 lambda expressions from this post but is it possible to write a Java 8 lambda in groovy". You say you know it does, then you retract it. Why can't you simply upgrade your Spock version to the latest?

Comment: Have you tried running your Java 8 code in your Spock test? Also, post an example of your Java8 lambda. There may be an easy Groovy way.

Comment: The post that I cite shows how the groovy compiler doesn't accept java8 syntax. I'm wondering if there is another way to construct a lambda expression that compiles. e.g. `new Function(...)`

Comment: If you are using Gradle, why not bump the version?

Comment: I cannot upgrade to the latest version of Spock because my project depends on groovy 1.x upgrading to 2.x would break the existing libraries I depend on.

Comment: I have upgraded projects in the past to use Groovy 2.4.1, the latest, you should be fine. Then you can upgrade spock. Upgrade them at the same time.

Comment: @JaredBurrows don't think upgrading is a option. I'm depending on a Titan release that uses groovy 1.8.9. When I upgrade to spock 1.0-groovy-2.4 I get org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 1.0.0-groovy-2.4 is not compatible with Groovy 1.8.9file:/Users/vallecu/.m2/repository/com/thinkaurelius/groovy-shaded-asm/groovy-shaded-asm/1.8.9/groovy-shaded-asm-1.8.9.jar

Comment: I have asked before, are you using `Gradle`? If so, can you please post your `build.gradle` so I can see your setup?

Comment: Nope I'm using maven. Updating spock isn't what I was inquiring about. I'm really interesting in the possibly of writing java 8 lambdas in groovy 1.x

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out you can use the `as` keyword in groovy 1.x to cast a groovy `Closure` to a java 8 lambda.

Consider the following java class

```
public class Foo {
    public static boolean getBar(Predicate<String> predicate) {
        return predicate.test("hello");
    }
}
```

From a Spock Test (in groovy) we can write

```
class FooSpecTest extends Specification {
    def "test foo"() {
        when:
        boolean result = Foo.getBar({x -> x.contains("blah")} as Predicate<String>)
        then:
        result == true
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!  I just learned about the as keyword when I was trying to pass the 's' character to a function and Groovy was interpreting it as a String.  's' as char (or was it Character) did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

### No, proposed for Groovy 3.0

### Not in latest 2.3/2.4.1:

Based on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906748/groovy-compiler-does-not-accept-java-8-lambdas?lq=1) you posted, it was already answered in those comments. You can try to use `Closures` instead.

Based off the official `Groovy` docs:

> Groovy 2.3 doesn’t support the new syntax constructs offered by Java 8
>   (such as lambdas, method references, default methods in interfaces,
>   etc), but you can very well already use the new APIs offered by JDK 8,
>   and even use Groovy closures in lieu of Java 8 lambdas.

You are using a much older `Groovy` version and if `2.3` does not support it, your version will not.

Source: http://www.groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.3.html

Nothing mentioned in 2.4(http://www.groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.4.html)