# Implementing Akka AbstractActor in Groovy produces compiler errors

Tags: java, groovy, akka

Groovy 2.4.7 here using the Akka Java API with Gradle coordinates: `com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.5.4`.

I'm trying to implement an `AbstractActor` and running into a potential conflict between the Java/Akka API and Groovy itself:

```
class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
    @Override
    Receive createReceive() {
        receiveBuilder()
            .match(DoSomething, message -> {
            // Implement message handler if message is of type DoSomething
            }).build()
    }
}
```

Produces the following compiler error:

> "*Groovy:expecting EOF, found ')' @ line 18, column 5.*"

I *think* it has something to do with the `->` operator used after message. Is there a fix or workaround for this in Groovy-land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up java's lambda expressions with groovy's closures. So it should be:

```
class MyActor extends AbstractActor {
    @Override
    Receive createReceive() {
        receiveBuilder()
            .match(DoSomething, { message ->
            // Implement message handler if message is of type DoSomething
            }).build()
    }
}
```

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23906748/groovy-compiler-does-not-accept-java-8-lambdas) as well.